# Initialize counter with result from previous run saved to a file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using a program using python that counts pulses with the GPIO and stores them in a text file.  How can I update that program in such a way that when the  program is restarted or else update the rapsberry pi, the counter will continue to count from the last count that was before?

```
counter = 0

def my_callback2(channel)

global counter
counter = counter + 1
print counter

file = open("testfile.txt", "w")
file.write(str(counter))

file.close()
with open('testfile.txt', 'r') as f:
    first_line = f.readline()

print "switch press detected"
```

Comment: can you show us the code?

Comment: instead of initializing your counter with 0, you initialize it on program start with the latest value from your text file.

Comment: You may read last value from that text file

Comment: What error do you get or what's wrong ?

Comment: there is nothing wrong.  All I want is that when I restart the program instead of begin count from 0, it will begin to count from the last count(pulse) meaning that if the last count was 40, it will begin from 40 not from 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be easier ways but this will do it:

```
order_idFile = open('some_file.txt', 'r') # open file for reading
order_id = int(order_idFile.read().strip()) # read file contents, strip it and convert a str to int
order_idFile.close() # close file
order_id += 1 # add 1 to current number
order_idFile = open('some_file.txt', 'w') # open file for writing 
order_idFile.write(str(order_id)) # convert int to str and write to file
order_idFile.close() # close file
```

---

**Note:**
`some_file.txt` must have a valid number (`0` perhaps?) the first time you run the script.